# Get the difference between to dates in minutes with Date-FNS - NaN Error

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I'm using the [Date-FNS](https://date-fns.org/) library to get the difference between to dates in minutes. Why does *minutesDifference* return **NaN**? 
My goal is to get number of minutes between the given dates. [Here is the link to the Date-FNS doc.](https://date-fns.org/v1.29.0/docs/differenceInMinutes)

```
 getDateTime: function () {
            var now = new Date()
            var year = now.getFullYear()
            var month = now.getMonth()
            var day = now.getDate()
            var hour = now.getHours()
            var minute = now.getMinutes()

            var dateTime = year + ', ' + month + ', ' + day + ', ' + hour + ', ' + minute + ', 0'

            var minutesDifference = differenceInMinutes(new Date(2018, 2, 30, 22, 55, 0), new Date(dateTime))
            return minutesDifference
          },
```

Comment: What are you doing in function `differenceInMinutes()` ? Please add the code to your question.

Comment: Getting the number of minutes between the given dates. https://date-fns.org/v1.29.0/docs/differenceInMinutes

Comment: Have you tried the other way around? `differenceInMinutes(new Date(dateTime), new Date(2018, 2, 30, 22, 55, 0))`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your value of `dateTime` is a string which is incorrect, you are passing 1 single param and not 6 different params to `Date()`.

Just do

```
differenceInMinutes(new Date(2018, 2, 30, 22, 55, 0), new Date())
```

`new Date` will take the current date/timestamp by default so you dont need to pass any params to it.

Please refer the docs: [`Date` - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Thanks, but how to pass a _generated_ date to the function? This didn't work, got **NaN**: `getDateTime: function () {
            var now = new Date()
            var year = now.getFullYear()
            var month = now.getMonth()
            var day = now.getDate()
            var hour = now.getHours()
            var minute = now.getMinutes()

            var dateTime = year + ', ' + month + ', ' + day + ', ' + hour + ', ' + minute + ', 0'

            var minutesDifference = differenceInMinutes(new Date(), new Date(dateTime))
            return minutesDifference
          },`

Comment: @Tom Is that the same code from your question? If you want to pass in param as 1 single string, make sure that the string is formatted correctly, so it comes out to be something like `Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00')`. Your string has comma separated values currently. Checkout the docs link in my answer.

Comment: Rahul, I tried your suggestion and a couple other variants without success. Here is a simple example code: `// import Date-FNS for minutesDifference, https://date-fns.org/v1.29.0/docs/differenceInMinutes 

getDateTime('2018, 3, 4, 15, 30, 0')

getDateTime: function (dateReminder) {
 var minutesDifference = differenceInMinutes(new Date(dateReminder), new Date())
console.log('minutesDifference: ' + minutesDifference)
}` **GOAL:** Pass a date to the function to get the difference in minutes.

Comment: [..2] By **hard coding** the date, it works though: `var minutesDifference = differenceInMinutes(new Date(2018, 3, 4, 15, 30, 0), new Date())` Any ideas what I need to change to pass a date to the function?

Comment: @Tom You seem to be doing the same mistake again. **Do not pass comma separated values to `Date()` like `'2018, 3, 4, 15, 30, 0'`**. From your code in the question, try doing `differenceInMinutes(new Date(2018, 2, 30, 22, 55, 0), new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0))`. Note that in the second date object, 6 different params are passed. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I tried your example and passed strings like `2014-02-11T11:30:30` - all resulted in **NaN**. Can you please show me an example? Maybe on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Tom can you create a jsfiddle and reproduce the error that you are getting?